# Variables exporting error in MongoDB error

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

**Question**

I have provided my code below for reference. I'm using **MongoDB** and **discord.js v12**. So basically, I have made a `!info` command which shows some general info of the user.

What this code does is, it checks through the member's roles, and regarding which role they have, it calculates their total claim time (for giveaways etc.). The problem here, is with the **`donator`** role. I can't figure out why I can't use the `donates` variable outside the `db.findOne` block. Here, `data.content.length` shows the total donates of the users, which means `donates * 5` is **`+5`** claim time for each donate.

**My Code**

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    name: 'info',
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord){
        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;

        const db = require('../models/d-schema');
        db.findOne({ guildid: message.guild.id, user: member.user.id }, async(err, data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(data){
              const donates = parseInt(data.content.length);
            }
          })

        var DefaultTime = 10;
        var support = 0;
        var donate = 0;
        var boost = 0;
       
        const userRoles = member.roles.cache.map((r) => r.name);
        
        if (userRoles.includes("୨・supporter")) {
          support = 3;
        }
    
        if (userRoles.includes("୨・donator")) {
          donate = donates * 5;
        }
        
        if (userRoles.includes("୨・booster")) {
          boost = 10;
        }
    
        const TotalTime = DefaultTime + support + donate + boost;

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL( {dynamic: true} ))
        
        .addFields(
            {name: member.user.tag, value: member.user, inline: true},
            {name: 'Nickname', value: `${member.nickname !== null ? member.nickname : 'None'}`, inline: true},
            {name: 'Is Bot', value: member.user.bot, inline: true},

            {name: 'Joined', value: `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("MMMM Do YYYY")}`, inline: true},
            {name: 'Created', value: `${moment.utc(member.user.createdAt).format("MMMM Do YYYY")}`, inline: true},
            {name: 'Claim Time', value: `${TotalTime} seconds`, inline: true},
        )

        .setFooter(`ID : ${member.user.id}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('00ffcc')

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `donates` variable because you are **declaring** it **inside** the `db.findOne()` block. This is called [variables scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). For better understanding you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

If you want to use it outside of that block, you have to **declare** it **beforehand**, like this:

```js
let donates;

db.findOne({ guildid: message.guild.id, user: member.user.id }, async(err, data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(data){
              donates = parseInt(data.content.length);
            }
          })
```

Now you're able to use that variable outside of the `db.findOne()` block :)

---

### Edit:

#### Alternative way:

It would be easier to use the function **asynchronously**. That way, everything can be scoped in the same block!

##### Example:

These two methods will give the same results:

```js
const data = await Model.findOne({ ... });
console.log(data);
```

```js
Model.findOne({ ... }, (err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

---

- Suggestion from [Lioness100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13721990/lioness100)

Comment: Yup Lioness100 is indeed OP